# Codeforces's problem 151A I've wrote this program in C language , I think it has some problem. Help me out please

Tags: c, dynamic-language-runtime

[151A codeforces link](https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/151/A)

Here is my code written in C language. It has some problem

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
 
int main ()
{
      int n,k,l,c,d,p,nl,np,mm,per,tl,to,sum;
      
      scanf("%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d",&n,&k,&l,&c,&d,&p,&nl,&np);
      mm = k*l;
      per = mm/nl;
      tl = c*d;
      to = p/np;
      sum=(per,tl,to)/n;
      printf("%d",sum);
      return 0;
}
```

Comment: `per,tl,to` What do you want that part to do?

Comment: sorry! I am new .

Comment: What are you trying to do, what do you expect and what do you get?

Comment: Always check the return value of `scanf()` before using any variables read by it.

Comment: Check the values before a division. Make sure you don't divide by `0` nor divide `INT_MIN` by `-1` when `-INT_MAX>INT_MIN` (because `INT_MIN/-1` would result in `-INT_MIN`, which is too large to store in `INT_MAX` when the systems uses two complement, which is extremely likely). Also, check the values before you multiply them, make sure you don't generate an overflow. Not doing this things causes UB.

Answer (score 1):

You have to find the minimum value among `per`, `tl`, and `to` and divide that with `n` instead of just calculating `to/n`, which you are currently calculating with `sum=(per,tl,to)/n;`. (`per` and `tl` are ignored according to the definition of the *comma operator*)

Comment: I didn't get you. can you please write the code here . I am so sorry for that, but I didn't understand it all